# how to set reactive array object value to null in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, reactive

I am developing an app using vuejs and I want to set the value of the section and subsection to empty.

Vuejs code

```
export default {
  name: 'CreateCourse',
  setup(){
      const sections = reactive([{'section_title': '', 'sub_sections': [{'sub_section_title': '', 'imageURL': '' as any, 'url': ''}]}]);

     sections.section_title = "";
    }
}
```

but I am getting error property section section_title does not exist. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: `sections` is an array, you can access with `sections[0].section_title `

Comment: Consider explaining your case. It's unlikely that you really do this like you showed because section_title is already empty string and doesn't need to be reassigned. A possible solution depends on a specific case.

Answer (score 0):

1. the value is array not an object, so it should be accessed like: `sections[0].section_title`
2. `reactive` expects an object to passed with key and reactive value. So in your example you should use `ref` instead.
3. (optional) setup function should return the state to be used in template

try to use:

```js
setup(){
     const sections = ref([{'section_title': '', 'sub_sections': [{'sub_section_title': '', 'imageURL': '' as any, 'url': ''}]}]);

     sections.value[0].section_title = "your_value";

     return {sections}; //(optional)
}
```

and in your template (optional):

```
{{ sections[0].section_title }}
```

Comment: Point 2 is not necessarily true. It's perfectly valid to use `reactive()` on arrays.